# Can you actually "want a need"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, nouns

I know it's a mouthful, but can you, actually? I ran across this line in my recent reading:

> For example, in *Little Caesar*, Rico has power and every material need he could ever want but he has no security because his fortune is based on illegal actions. ([source](https://books.google.com/books?id=uu4AuZeLrRYC&pg=PA292&dq=%22need%20he%20could%20ever%20want%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjO693HoamEAxVoODQIHds4DQAQ6AF6BAgIEAI#v=onepage&q=%22need%20he%20could%20ever%20want%22&f=false))

Searching on Google Books let me to this this

> ...igniting all the need he could ever want. ([source](https://books.google.com/books?id=obp7YiLZUQYC&pg=PA127&dq=%22need%20he%20could%20ever%20want%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjO693HoamEAxVoODQIHds4DQAQ6AF6BAgJEAI#v=onepage&q=%22need%20he%20could%20ever%20want%22&f=false))

I find this usage slightly odd because normally needs are had or met, not wanted, but let's see what the dictionaries say. Oxford Languages offers one definition, through Google, that seems to fit the bill

> a thing that is wanted or required

This is vague. It seems to explain the usage I encountered but at the same time seems to fit better with the conventional sense of a requirement or a lack, as showcased in its own example that follows. All other dictionaries I have checked don't have a similar definition. Some of the closest definitions are listed here:

> a lack of something requisite, desirable, or useful (M-W)
> a physiological or psychological requirement for the well-being of an organism (M-W)

> a strong feeling that you want somebody/something or must have something (Oxford)
> the things that somebody requires in order to live in a comfortable way or achieve what they want (Oxford)

> [USUALLY PLURAL] something that you need in order to be healthy, comfortable, successful, etc. (Macmillan)

Going by these definitions, you can't really **want** a need. Can you though?

Comment: As a matter of English grammar and usage, of course you can want a need. Or you can lobotomize a potato, or interrupt a fork. Nonsense, to be sure, but you can say it. So what's really in question is what these authors meant by wanting a need, and that's a matter of opinion. Might try contacting them.

Comment: In context, the examples are okay. Floating alone, less so: "You can't really want a need."

Comment: When you say something like "every need", it's a very general concept. Qualifying with "he could ever want" narrows it down to just those needs that the specific subject cares about.

Comment: Cambria Press is listed on Wikipedia under [List of companies engaged in the self-publishing business](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:List_of_companies_engaged_in_the_self-publishing_business). This is not necessarily bad, but they probably don't have editors on staff.

Comment: It's certainly possible to, by metonymy, want a need (that is, something you need) and also to not want it:  a small child who needs to eat his supper and to go to bed may not want his supper but wants to go to bed because he's tired.  But that would not apply to these situations

Comment: " all the X he could ever want" is kind of a set phrase meaning a very large amount, and probably shouldn't be taken literally.

Answer (score 1):

The first example isn't well-constructed. The intended meaning is
"Rico has power and every material thing he could ever want".
The "things wanted" and "needs" are mixed up.

The second example is a description of a sexual interaction where everything is mixed up anyhow. If one insists on reading it strictly, the one partner might want to excite need in the other partner, and that could be a wanted (by him) need (in her). But... it's porn.

Comment: I suppose an inveterate do-gooder may feel aggrieved if there seems to be no need to meet.